# NameError: uninitialized constant Gem::SourceIndex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

This error appears for a new rails app, with nothing modified, when visiting the homepage (after successfully running `bundle install`).

Here are the version numbers:

`ruby: 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-darwin12.2.1]`

`rails: 3.2.12`

`rvm: 1.18.14`

`gem: 2.0.0`

`bundler: 1.3.0.pre.8`

Calling `which ruby` returns `/Users/J/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby`, which seems fishy, right?

Comment: Got the same error after upgrade from Ruby 1.9.3-p385 to 1.9.3-p392. Could it be a coincidence with some other change in my app?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15079182/cant-run-rails-server-after-accidentally-running-gem-update-system/15090490#15090490) seems related

Answer (score 59):

You need to update Bundler: `gem update bundler`

RubyGems release 2.0 [seems to be the trigger](http://blog.rubygems.org/2013/02/24/2.0.0-released.html) for the error:

> RubyGems 2.0 includes several new features and many breaking changes. Some of these changes will cause existing software to break. . . . If you are using bundler be sure to install a 1.3.0.prerelease version or newer. Older versions of bundler will not work with RubyGems 2.0.

Here are the [issue details](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/536).

---

EDIT, 2023: I run this update every morning when I sit down to work. It's kept me out of trouble:

```bash
gem update --system && gem update bundler pry
```

Comment: You should copy the actual text of the answer here so your answer doesn't become worthless due to a broken link in the future.

Comment: Its now Sep. 8th 2022 and this somehow still applies.  Ruby is 3.1.2.  Bundler is at 2.3.7 but the latest is 2.3.22.  Rails is at 7.0.3.1 but when it does `bundle install` during a `rails new`, I get the same `uninitialized constant Gem::Source (NameError)` error.  `gem update bundler` solved my issue.

Comment: Yep, this answer is still relevant today when making a fresh install of Rails under some circumstances.

Comment: Every day when I sit down to work: `gem update --system && gem update bundler pry`

Answer (score 31):

**Thanks!**

Rails-7, ruby 3.1.2, had the same issue

solved it by `gem update --system`

Comment: this is the modern day real answer

Answer (score 18):

Run:

```
gem update --system 1.8.24
```

Sounds like there's something buggy with latest.

Comment: A colleague had updated to latest rubygems and was getting the same error as OP.  I updated to latest to ensure that I got the same error.  I did.  I used the above answer to revert (to 1.8.25) and the error was resolved.

Answer (score 15):

Have you tried updating your RubyGems?

```
gem update --system
```

Comment: same error and yes it says:  Latest Version currently installed.  Aborting.  

Still get error.

Answer (score 3):

```
gem update bundle && gem update --system
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how it will fix the issue?

Comment: in your project root directory,using the commands,remember to use "bundle install"

Answer (score 0):

For me it was all of the above + using the new one on my nginx config.