# Can't run rspec when using Rails 5 and acts-as-taggable-on 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, acts-as-taggable-on

## Versions

- Ruby: 2.3.3
- Bundler: 1.14.6
- Rails: 5.0.2
- acts-as-taggable-on: 4.0.0
- Rspec: 3.5.4

## Gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0', '>= 5.0.0.1'
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '~> 4.0'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.5'
end
```

## Logic

lib/acts_as_taggable_on/generic_parser.rb

```
class MyParser < ActsAsTaggableOn::GenericParser
  def parse
    ActsAsTaggableOn::TagList.new.tap do |tag_list|
      tag_list.add @tag_list.split(',').map(&:strip).reject(&:empty?)
    end
  end
end
```

## Exception

When running `rpsec`, got these errors:

```
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:94:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'acts-as-taggable-on'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
Gem Load Error is: uninitialized constant ActsAsTaggableOn::GenericParser
```

How to fix it?

Comment: did you try with `gem update bundler` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15060011/nameerror-uninitialized-constant-gemsourceindex#15937572

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio Thank you for your comment. I tried `gem update bundler` just now. Now bundler version became `1.15.4`, but the same 
error happened when run `rspec`.

Comment: ok what about upgrading to `gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '~> 5.0'` and `gem 'bundler', '~> 1.15', '>= 1.15.4'` and `gem 'rspec', '~> 3.6'`?

Sorry this is really a stupid advise, but you are using `rails 5` so why not use the latest versions of everything? maybe this problem was solved with the later versions?
For the latest versions refer to 
https://rubygems.org/

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio Your advise is a way. I used a logic includes `ActsAsTaggableOn::GenericParser` and I added the source to the question. Now I am trying to use another way to realize the same result then remove that source. And rspec works. Maybe that's the version problem between several gems. Thank you very much for your follow.

Comment: Please provide full trace, not only exception.

Comment: also - how do you run your rspecs? Did you try `bundle exec rspec`?

Comment: @meta I have changed method and the error didn't happened. It must be a bug I think. I used `bundle exec rspec`, but not that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file name is incorrect, you have

```
lib/acts_as_taggable_on/generic_parser.rb
```

If the class is MyParser Rails need to map to that class via the name of the file which should be my_parser.rb and thus it should be

```
lib/acts_as_taggable_on/my_parser.rb
```